# Angular-froala is not updating the ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, froala, ngmodel

HTML:

```
<textarea froala="froalaOptions" ng-model="froalaContent"></textarea>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.froalaContent = '';

  $scope.froalaOptions = {
    placeholderText: '<i class="fa fa-book placeholder-icon"></i> Share your story',
    events: {
      'froalaEditor.focus': function () {
        angular.element('.feed .fr-toolbar').css('display', 'block');
      },
      'froalaEditor.blur': function () {
        angular.element('.feed .fr-toolbar').css('display', 'none');
      }
    }
  }
```

Order of JavaScript inclusions:

```
"vendor/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js",
"vendor/angularjs/plugins/angular-froala-master/jquery-embedly.js",
"vendor/angularjs/plugins/angular-froala-master/froala-editor.js",
"vendor/angularjs/plugins/angular-froala-master/froala-sanitize.js",
"vendor/angularjs/plugins/angular-froala-master/angular-froala.js",
"vendor/angularjs/plugins/angular-froala-master/embedly.min.js",
"vendor/angularjs/plugins/angular-froala-master/video.min.js",
"vendor/angularjs/plugins/angular-froala-master/image.min.js",
"vendor/angularjs/plugins/angular-froala-master/lists.min.js",
"vendor/angularjs/plugins/angular-froala-master/image.min.js",
"vendor/angularjs/plugins/angular-froala-master/colors.min.js",
"vendor/angularjs/plugins/angular-froala-master/font_size.min.js",
"vendor/angularjs/plugins/angular-froala-master/font_family.min.js",
```

---

In the function `ctrl.updateModelView()` in `angular-froala.js`, I can see that the value is being updated correctly, but it just doesn't seem to pass the value back to the parent scope. No matter what I do, whenever I log the $scope of my controller, froalaContent is always equal to an empty string.

I somehow managed to get it to work earlier by changing the ng-model on the HTML element to `ng-model="$parent.froalaContent"` but that doesn't seem to be working anymore.

I've been studying the documents for a while now and I feel like I have everything in its proper place, can anyone share some insight as to where I've gone wrong? Could it be I'm using an out-of-date version of jQuery or did I mess up the order of file inclusions?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but on the newer versions of Angular. I've used a workaround which is to use the keyup event and update the model manually.